# Open Atom Window in Full Screen

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

How do I configure my atom init script such that when I type `atom .` in Terminal, a new Atom window opens up *already in full-screen mode*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(atom.workspace), 'window:toggle-full-screen')
```

Comment: hmm, added this to the atom init script, rebooted Atom and my full-screen atom session did the above described behavior...however, my computer switched focus  to the desktop (instead of staying in the full screen Atom app). Was retaining focus in the Atom full-screen mode the purpose of the question?